# Using Associated Press photos

Tags: images, copyright, photo

I am kinda unclear on how/if I can use AP photos.  There are quite a few sites that use it with a credit underneath it.  Is that enough?  Do you still need the express written consent they talk about on their site?  Does anyone run a site using AP photos?

Answer (score 1):

They have a page called "[Buy AP Photos](https://www.ap.org/content/photos)". I'd say that implies they require either purchase or licensing. That page also lists whom to contact about it:

> To reprint AP photos/graphics for commercial or editorial use
> E-mail:apimages@ap.org
> Fax:+1.212.621.1955.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20120226023259/http://www.ap.org/pages/about/faq.html) you need to submit a request in writing.

Comment: Ya I saw that too, but if you are writing a news story, won't it take too long to turn around a request like that?  That's why I was hoping to hear from someone who's done it before...everytime I want to use one and writing for permission seems...onerous.

Answer (score 0):

**Newspapers or TV stations** can enter into agreements between the Associated Press and their organization for content licensing. However, since you asked only about images, I'm assuming that you're not an online newspaper.

Besides for that, there are **two options**:

**First**, and I [quote the AP](https://web.archive.org/web/20120226023259/http://www.ap.org/pages/about/faq.html#5):

> If you are not a member of The Associated Press, but want to receive AP news for your Web site or wireless service, company intranet, desktop or other interactive application, you can contact AP Digital by e-mail at *APDigital@ap.org*.

You may be able to discuss multiple image licensing with AP Digital, if that is what you want (as I understand from your comment on BenV's answer).

**Second**, as [John Conde points out](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4639/using-associated-press-photos/#4641), AP Images may be able to help you out as well, and they may also be able to answer questions about multiple image licensing.

Or, if for some odd reason you should prefer to use traditional mail (dunno why since you're here on Webmasters, but still), AP's licensing division can be reached at:

> Copyright
> The Associated Press
> 450 W. 33rd St.
> New York, NY 10001

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 you no longer need to contact the AP via email or snail mail about using their images.   They have a site where you can purchase subscriptions to use their images: http://www.apimages.com/

Their [how to purchase](http://www.apimages.com/PhotoChoice-Creative-Stock-About) page lists several options which allow you to download a number of stock images and use them non-exclusively without recurring payments; or purchase time limited licenses for images based on placement, project, and image size.

Comment: They don't seem to be very transparent on their subscription charges